# iOS ScrollView pager bounce issue when contained inside UINavigationControler

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

There're some good example of implement custom pager view using ScrollView like:
https://github.com/MarcBruins/BWWalkthrough-Xamarin-iOS

https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough

Above sample work well, but if I have a **UINavigationController** as root contorller, and push above pager view as a child;
 when scroll to switch page(drag and move both horizontally and vertically before drop), the whole pager view also moves vertically, this is not as expected.

does any has idea how to disable this vertically move(or bounce) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad(){
        ...
        _pagedViewController.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, topMargin + pagerHeight, frame.Width, frame.Height);
        ...

        //AddChildViewController(_pagedViewController);
        View.AddSubview(_pagedViewController.View);
        //_pagedViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);

        ...
    }
```

I've wrap page view inside container controler, and had code above, I've now fix issue by comment out two lines above.

I've found if I change pageview's height, also got vertical scroll problem, but this can be avoid by other fix.